Hyperboloid model: isometric embedding of hyperbolic plane into Minkowski space
The hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic plane allows one to view the hyperbolic plane as a submanifold of Minkowski space $\mathbb R^{2,1}$, through the parametrisation
$$
x_1 = \sinh u\cos v \\
x_2 = \sinh u\sin v \\
x_3 = \cosh u.
$$
The hyperbolic plane can also be viewed abstractly as the space $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with the Riemannian metric $\frac{dy_1^2 + dy_2^2}{y_2^2}$.
I am looking for an explicit expression for the isometric embedding of the abstract formulation of the hyperbolic plane (in coordinates $y_1,y_2$) to the hyperboloid in Minkowski space. I haven't been able to find this online. The classic parametrisation written above is clearly not it, since it is periodic in $v$.
A reference or derivation for such embedding would be greatly appreciated.

You mistakenly omitted the condition $y_2>0$. As for an explicit map, this was asked several times on this site and you can also find it in some hyperbolic geometry textbooks, like Ratcliffe.

I recommend https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/RFG/cannon.pdf

For instance, essentially the same question was asked earlier this month here.
